# I have a corpus file which was made by doc2bow function of gensim but I have lost the dictionary file. How do I get the dictionary file back

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, gensim

I have a corpus file which was made using `dictionary.doc2bow` function of gensim but I have lost the dictionary file. Is there any way I can get the dictionary file by doing something on the corpus file using gensim